# How to create a table programatically in Stimulsoft?

Tags: c#, .net, reporting, stimulsoft

I am trying to add a table after an image added to a page of StiReport. I have tried the code below but it throws an exception: ***Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration***

```
        stiReport1.Pages[0].Components.Clear();
        StiImage image = new StiImage();
        image.Left = 0;
        image.Top = 0;
        image.Width = 7;
        image.Height = 4;
        image.Stretch = true;
        //An image name should be unique in your report
        image.Name = "MyUniqueName";

        //Assign an image
        image.Image = bmp;

        //Add a component with an image with a report
        stiReport1.Pages[0].Components.Add(image);

        //Create Table
        StiTable table = new StiTable();
        table.Name = "MyUniqueName2";
        table.AutoWidth = StiTableAutoWidth.Table;
        table.AutoWidthType = StiTableAutoWidthType.FullTable;
        table.ColumnCount = 2;
        table.RowCount = 3;
        table.HeaderRowsCount = 1;
        table.FooterRowsCount = 0;
        table.Width = stiReport1.Pages[0].Width;
        table.Height = stiReport1.Pages[0].GridSize;
        //Set text on header
        StiTableCell headerCell = new StiTableCell();
        headerCell.Text.Value = "ddd";
        headerCell.ID = 0;
      //  headerCell.Border = new StiBorder(StiBorderSides.All, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0), 0, StiPenStyle.Solid);
        headerCell.HorAlignment = StiTextHorAlignment.Center;
        headerCell.VertAlignment = StiVertAlignment.Center;
        headerCell.WordWrap = true;
        headerCell.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("B Nazanin", 7F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        headerCell.Height = 3;
        table.TableStyle = StiTableStyle.Style32;

        table.Components.Clear();
        table.Components.Add(headerCell);
         stiReport1.Pages[0].Components.Add(table);
        //
        stiReport1.Compile();
        stiReport1.Render();
        stiReport1.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create at least one StiTableCell. StiTable is very complicated component. To get how to create it in code, try to create report with Table Band in Designer and look at the Code tab.